# Binding for an EntitySet is displaying values that aren't there?

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, data-binding, entity

I'm binding an ItemsControl to an EntitySet in a WPF application.  Its not acting as expected, however.  The ItemsControl is behaving as if it is *caching* the contents of the EntitySet between binds!

**Here's the stripped down code**:

The entity:

```
public partial class Item : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private EntitySet<Item> _Children;
    public EntitySet<Item> Children {get{return _children;}}
    /*...*/    
}
```

My partial class:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public void RemoveChild(Item child)
    {
        Children.Remove(child);
        // this finds PropertyChanged; defined in the Entity class
        SendPropertyChanged("Children");
    }
}
```

The UI:

```
<ItemsControl
    Name="ItemChildren"
    Background="CornflowerBlue"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type d:Item}">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Name}/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Code that demonstrates the behavior** (assume >2 Items, each having a single child):

```
this.ScrewyItem = Db.Items.First();
this.DataContext = ScrewyItem;
return;
```

Later, I remove the child from the entity:

```
ScrewyItem.RemoveChild(ScrewyItem.Children.First());
return;
```

After this code runs, the UI does not update and the Item is shown to have all children.  Notice that this method calls NotifyPropertyChanged, so the bindings should update!

Later, we remove this item from the UI bindings:

```
this.DataContext = Db.Items.Last(); //different item
return;
```

And then bind it to the UI again later

```
this.DataContext = ScrewyItem;
```

You would assume that AT LEAST at this point the UI would show the correct child list.  **This is *not* the case**, however!  It shows the **same** list of children as originally shown!

What's even more bizarre, if I put a breakpoint on my Children accessor, I can see that **the list is accessed when I rebind to the UI** *and* **the list does not contain the child I removed.**

The only way I can see that the UI could be doing this is if the contents of the Children collection are cached between binds.

**What is going on here?  What am I missing???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this.  It kind of sucks.

I can wrap the Children collection in a BindingList:

```
public IBindingList BindableChildren
{
    get
    {
        return new BindingList<Item>(Children);
    }
}
```

and then modify my RemoveChild method thusly:

```
this.Children.Remove(arg);
SendPropertyChanged("BindableChildren");
```

This results in the UI updating the list immediately and stops exhibiting the caching behavior.

The question still remans: **WTF?** and **Is there another way?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but perhaps the `ItemsControl` is listening for events from `IBindingList` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` and not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Bindings don't cache values, do they?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that the behavior you see is not a result of caching but a result of binding not wokring, that is updates to your data is not seen by the control.

Comment: Depends on your definition of Cache, the binding collects the data in the object at creation then listens for the event that notifies that the object has changed. however this means that if the value is changed with out the events it is listening to being fired then it never triggers the bindings update. for a property this is INotifyPropertyChanged so if you changed the value inside your "Item" then it would work but your not changing the Item your changing the EntitySet which fires a ListChanged event not the CollectionChanged event bindings listen to